# Gulp как узнать ссылки переданные в src?

Tags: node.js, javascript

Вопрос в комментариях.

```
   var gulp = require('gulp'),
    plugin   = require('plugin');

    gulp.task('task', function(){
        gulp.src(['path1', 'path2'])
        .pipe(plugin()); 
        // как в вызываемом методе plugin получить 
        // получить массив-ссылки переданные в src?
    });
```

Comment: сомнительно что можно, т.к. в результате src оно вызывает вот это https://github.com/wearefractal/glob-stream/blob/master/index.js#L64 , а это превращается в stream для  pipe... в общем почему бы вам не сделать этот массив отдельной переменной и не юзать в plugin() ?

Comment: эстетически не красиво получается, если передавать ещё и в plugin.  
А это в указанный Вами метод передается массив с ссылками? Сейчас жутко голова уже не соображает, но завтра посмотрю, если эти ссылки попадают в glob, то может есть возможность эти ссылки от туда же и вытащить. Если я не ошибаюсь, то этот же инстенс glob можно подключить и в самом plugin...

Comment: https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/blob/master/index.js#L25 -> https://github.com/wearefractal/vinyl-fs/blob/master/lib/src/index.js#L17 -> https://github.com/wearefractal/glob-stream/blob/master/index.js#L64

Answer (score 1):

На самом деле это не "ссылки", а паттерны, которые Gulp разименовывает в поток файлов. И список этих паттернов нельзя получить в плагине.

Тут скорее вопрос зачем изначальные паттерны нужны в плагине? В большинстве случаев, при нормальной логике создания/комбинирования плагинов, основное значение имеет контент файлов (ну и их имена), а не то, что было изначально переданно в "Gulp.src".

UPD:

Кстати, массив

```
['src/*.js', '!src/test.js']
```

тоже является валидным набор паттернов. :)